# WinRT PointerRoutedEventArgs.GetCurrentPoint Method throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, touch, windows-8.1

I develop a multi touch WinRT app in C# for Windows 8.1 and test it on Surface Pro 2.
I hooked up on the PointerMoved event of MainPage. On the received `PointerRoutedEventsArg` I call `GetCurrentPoint` and specify the `MainPage` as the parameter. For most points this works, for some I get an `ArgumentException`.

```
Exception:Thrown: "Wrong parameter". 
Failed to get pointer information.
WinRT information: Failed to get pointer information.
```

What does this error mean in the context of `GetCurrentPoint`? Why does it work for some points, but not for others? Finally, what to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistake of storing the PointerRoutedEventArgs object in my application. Apparently these objects are reused by WinRT, so whenever an object was reused before I called GetCurrentPoint, I ran into the exception. The solution was to imediatly call GetCurrentPoint when the PointerRoutedEventArg object became available and to store the resulting Point data instead